# Plotting complex functions in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, complex-numbers

I have the following code

```
x = linspace(-pi, pi, 1e3);
y = sqrt((x).^(1/2));
plot(x, real(y));
plot(x, imag(y));
```

The value at x=-1 on the real and imaginary plots are both 0.7071 (sqrt(0.5). Why is it not 0 (real) and 1 (imaginary)? When I enter this code:

```
real((-1)^(1/2))
imag((-1)^(1/2))
```

this gives me 0 (real) and 1 (imaginary) as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `sqrt((x).^(1/2)) = x.^(1/4)`

This is **not** all imaginary since `(-i)^4 = i^4 = -1*-1 = 1`. Consider what happens on the complex plane and you should be able to arrive at the conclusion that if `y^4 = -1` then `y = exp(i*(2*N-1)*pi/4)` where `N` is any integer.

This leads to 4 unique solutions for `y` which are `+/-sqrt(2)/2 +/- i*sqrt(2)/2`. MATLAB returns the one where both real and imaginary are positive.

Comment: Wow. I completely missed that I had sqrt(sqrt(x)). Thanks very much.